# Put a PNG image over a background image

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to replicate http://www.milkbardigital.com.au/ as a learning project in react.

Currently I'm struggling to get the PNG image over the top of the background image.

Here's my code,

```
import React from 'react';
import {Image} from 'react-bootstrap';

export default React.createClass ( {
    render() {
        var background = {backgroundSize : 'cover'};
        var textStyle = {
            position: 'absolute',
            top: '50%',
            left: '50%'
        };

        return (
            <div style={{width: 'auto'}}>
                <Image
                    style={background} responsive
                    src="http://www.milkbardigital.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Milkbar-Home-Background.jpg">
                </Image>
                <h1 style={textStyle}>Agile Media Content</h1>

            </div>
        );
    }
});



<Image src="http://www.milkbardigital.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Milkbar-Digital-Media.png" responsive/>
```

This "Image src" I've tried to place inside the above code but it won't work.

Anyone able to work this out?

It's with React Bootstrap!

Thanks,

Edit - - -

I've worked out how to get it slightly on top, now trying to get it put in the right position.

This is the code, ignore the opacity part,

/**
 * Created by Hewlbern on 21-Jan-17.
 */

```
import React from 'react';
import {Image} from 'react-bootstrap';

export default React.createClass ( {
    render() {
        var background = {backgroundSize : 'cover',
        opacity: '0.5',
        };
        var textStyle = {
            position: 'absolute',
            top: '50%',
            left: '50%'
        };
        var ontop = {
            display: 'block',
            margin: 'auto',
            width: '50%',
        };

        return (
            <div style={{width: 'auto'}}>
                <Image
                    style={background} responsive
                    src="http://www.milkbardigital.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Milkbar-Home-Background.jpg">
                </Image>
                <h1 style={textStyle}>Agile Media Content</h1>
                <Image style={textStyle} responsive src="http://www.milkbardigital.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Milkbar-Digital-Media.png" />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you try wrapping Image with a div and apply your background to div?

Comment: No I haven't - Could you give me an example? I'll try that now.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an example code. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577157/place-transparent-image-over-background-image

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at that now. Cheers Madura!

Comment: Check this
https://jsfiddle.net/madura/xxrL7apg/
Is this what you want?

Comment: Hi Madura, no, Take a look at http://www.milkbardigital.com.au/ - I want the PNG image they are using to overlay the background image on there hero display. (if that makes sense!)

Comment: I think I've worked it out - well sort of. Will post an edit.